# Error create SQL model connection. Eclipse to mysql

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jpa, jdbc

I have created Driver definitions on Eclipse connect to mysql 8.0.23. when test connection, ping succeeded but can't connect.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either the driver package is not in the corresponding directory of eclipse, or the driver package version is not correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The driver package version is correct. So could you tell me more about "the driver package is not in the corresponding directory of eclipse".

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after I attempted to selectively install the Data Tools. In particular, after clicking "Next" the top two fields (Name and Description) were blank. I also didn't have a long list of connection profile types, only Generic JDBC and the ones I created.

I eventually installed 100% of everything from Data Tools except for sources, and this finally resolved.